# Plain text being cut off at bottom in iOS, how to fix in xCode?

Tags: ios, fonts, interface-builder, uilabel

I noticed in my iOS app, for text that are using a system font with size 20 pt or more, the bottom of text is being cut off.

For example, the bottom portion of the letters y, g, p, and g are being cut off.

How do I fix this in Xcode?

Comment: Provide more details. Is this text in a `UILabel` or a `UITextField` or something else? Provide relevant details about how it is setup.

Comment: @rmaddy Strange remark. Just add an UILabel with the text "you are lazy" and height same as pointSize to the view and you'll see the effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your using something like a UILabel it means you will need to increase the vertical height of that element.. Either in code or in interface builder.

If you are doing it in code you can get the label to resize itself to fit the contents by calling sizeToFit..

```
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Alternatively you could measure the size to the string by using `sizeWithAttributes:` then change the size of the label accordingly.

Comment: Im strictly uses interface builder. So guess i either drag the text box corners to resize it or edit the size inspector. Thanks

Comment: The appropriate way would be to calculate the size, especially if you are to localize your app or if you use the system font (which can be changed by the user to a much larger font).

Answer (score 2):

Updating this one for Swift 3.x in a `UITableViewController`.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after the problematic label is set, but before the cell is returned from the method, add a line something like this:

```
cell.myLabelWhoseCharactersLikegyqGetCutOff.sizeToFit()
```